# Can one set Clickhouse settings via JDBC connection? What is interactive mode?

Tags: join, jdbc, clickhouse

Due to some use cases with JOINs in a special scenario I'd like to change settings in clickhouse and would like to know if it's possible to change the settings via a Java JDBC connection. Example:

`SET allow_experimental_multiple_joins_emulation = 1;`

I get some errors, but I'm not sure of this is a JDBC limitation. Clickhouse doc talks about interactive mode for CLI, but not sure what's possible with JDBC?

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/

Comment: You need to set JDBC connection property `session_id` to any string. It will be identifier of your session. After that you can use `SET allow_experimental_multiple_joins_emulation = 1;` . Or you can change it in users's profile at server.

Comment: _"I get some errors"_, when asking errors, please be as complete as possible. When you get errors, show us those errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with Clickhouse v20.1.2.4, 2020-01-22 this setting has become obsolete:

*"The settings allow_experimental_data_skipping_indices, allow_experimental_cross_to_join_conversion and allow_experimental_multiple_joins_emulation are now obsolete and do nothing."*

[cite: Clickhouse changelog](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) and corresponding [git pull request](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/7974)